# How to find matching patterns from two different files

Tags: regex, scripting

I have these two files, and would like to find the matching patterns
for the second file based on the entries from the first file, then print out the 
matched results.

Here is the first file,

```
switch1  Ethernet2   4     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet4   4     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet7   4     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet9   4     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet10  4     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet13  1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet14  1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet15  1     4     5  
switch2  Ethernet5   4     4     5  
switch2  Ethernet6   1     4     5  
switch2  Ethernet7   4     5  
switch2  Ethernet8   1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet1   2002  2697  2523  
switch1  Ethernet17  2002  2576  2515  
switch1  Ethernet11  2002  2621  2617  
switch2  Ethernet1   2001  2512  2577
```

And here is the second file,

```
switch1  Ethernet1   1   4  5  40  2002  2523  2590  2621  2656  2661  2665  2684  2697  2999  
switch1  Ethernet2   1   4  5  40  2002  2504  2505  2508  2514  2516  2517  2531  2533  2535  2544  2545  2547  2549  2555  2566  2571  2575  2589  2590  2597  2604  2611  2626  2629  2649  2666  2672  2684  2691  2695  
switch1  Ethernet3   40  
switch1  Ethernet4   1   4  5  40  2002  2504  2516  2517  2535  2547  2549  2571  2579  2590  2597  2604  2605  2620  2624  2629  2649  2684  2695  
switch1  Ethernet5   1   4  5  40  55    56    2000  2002  2010  2037  2128  2401  2409  2504  2526  2531  2540  2541  2548  2562  2575  2578  2579  2588  2590  2597  2604  2606  2608  2612  2615  2616  2621  2638  2640  2645  2650  2666  2667  2669  2670  2674  2678  2684  2690  2696  
switch1  Ethernet6   40  
switch1  Ethernet7   1   4  5  40  2037  2128  2174  2401  2409  2463  2526  2535  2540  2541  2544  2562  2578  2579  2590  2616  2621  2625  2631  2645  2659  2667  2670  2674  2678  2682  2684  2690  2696  
switch1  Ethernet8   1   4  5  40  2037  2128  2396  2401  2409  2420  2531  2619  2640  2653  2658  2669  2677  2683  2684  
switch1  Ethernet9   1   4  5  40  2128  2169  2396  2401  2409  2420  2504  2515  2531  2553  2578  2597  2619  2621  2640  2658  2669  2677  2683  2684  2694  
switch1  Ethernet10  1   4  5  40  2079  2128  2169  2378  2396  2453  2509  2578  2591  2597  2621  2634  2641  2657  
switch1  Ethernet11  1   4  5  40  2002  2128  2169  2396  2453  2509  2512  2520  2526  2549  2552  2564  2571  2575  2589  2591  2597  2611  2617  2621  2634  2641  2657  2671  2676  2686  2694  
switch1  Ethernet12  1   4  5  40  2079  2378  2396  2453  2515  2531  2553  2597  2619  2621  2640  2657  2669  2677  2684  2694  
switch1  Ethernet13  1   4  5  40  2174  2396  2453  2463  2508  2524  2531  2536  2546  2567  2597  2629  2640  2657  2669  2674  2684  
switch1  Ethernet14  1   4  5  40  2524  2536  2544  2567  2575  2582  2628  2640  2659  2674  2681  2689  
switch1  Ethernet15  1   4  5  40  2515  2553  2575  2582  2621  2628  2640  2681  2689  2694  
switch1  Ethernet16  1   4  5  40  2513  2539  2544  2553  2561  2573  2575  2582  2619  2640  2670  2681  
switch1  Ethernet17  1   4  5  40  2002  2508  2513  2515  2531  2538  2539  2544  2547  2553  2561  2570  2573  2575  2576  2582  2586  2601  2608  2619  2621  2640  2658  2670  2681
```

the results should display,

```
switch1  Ethernet13  1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet14  1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet15  1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet8   1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet16  1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet1   2002  2697  2523  
switch1  Ethernet17  2002  2576  2515
```

The challenging part for me is that I don't know
how to compare a pattern from one line of the first file to all the lines of the second file. And in this case, it has 5 patterns to match, when the second file doesn't have
consistent fields to work with. Some lines are shorter than the others, and the matching fields may not be the same with other lines.
Any idea or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: You'll need to explain why you should get that output.

Comment: I just need to compare and find the mismatched entries and fix those. This is just a simplified version only. thanks for getting back to me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, but there's probably a better way

```
#!/bin/bash

patternfile='file1'
exec 4<$patternfile
otherfile='file2'

while read -u4 pattern; do
    grep ".*`echo ""$pattern"" | sed 's/\s\+/ \\\+.* /g'`.*" $otherfile
done
```

P.S. This doesn't output all of the lines you said you wanted:
Ethernet8 is switch2 in one and switch1 in the other. fixing that in regex would be really ugly, but you could use awk to get only the records you want.
Ethernet16 isn't even in the first file, I think that line is a mistake.
Ethernet1 and Ethernet17 have the records out of order, which my solution can't deal with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try and let you know. Really appreciated.

Comment: still not working yet, but let see if I can make it to work with this code. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add some details for your While loop here ? it didn't come back with any result. Sorry ! I'm still pretty new to scripting. Thanks

Comment: the exec statement near the top outputs the contents of file1 to stream 4, the read -u4 command reads one line at a time from stream 4 and returns true unless it reads an EOF.

Comment: Thanks genisage ! what about the "pattern" ? is it an array ? or the "patternfile" ? I tried both, but none was returned ?

Comment: You read patternfile in one line at a time and store each line in $pattern. So pattern is a string like "switch1  Ethernet9   4     4     5"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! Actually, Ethernet1 and Ethernet17 should be part of the solution. Is there a way to get them in ? It works for some entries.

Comment: One more request please, how do I print out all the lines from "otherfile" that don't match with the "patternfile" ? Thanks

Comment: At this point I would recommend just writing it in perl or python.